# How do I get rid of the Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have been on this for a long time but couldn't figure out the reason for segmentation fault.

I have a feeling that something is wrong with writting into the buffer multiple times but I don't know any alternate methods. Or it might be a problem with memory allocation.

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover filename\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No file found\n");
        return 2;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char buffer[512];

    int counter = 0;

    char imagename[8];

    FILE* image;

    while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1)
    {
        if(buffer[0] == 0xff &&
           buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
           buffer[2] == 0xff &&
           (buffer[0] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 )
        {
             if(counter > 0)
             {
                fclose(image);
             }
             sprintf(imagename, "%03i.jpg", counter);

             image = fopen(imagename, "w");

             if(!image)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr, "No file found\n");
                    return 2;
            }

             fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, image);

             printf("%i", counter);
             counter++;

        }

        else if(counter > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, image);
        }

    }
    fclose(image);
    fclose(file);
    free(image);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `free(image)` makes no sense. It's a `FILE*`, and you already `fclose`-d it.

Comment: At first I had use FILE* image = malloc(sizeof(FILE)). But then I removed it because I was getting the seg fault (trial and error!!). I forgot to delete free(image). I have edited the code and it still has that seg fault. Can you see any other problem?

Comment: run your program in a debugger so in the future you can see which line is causing the segfault, then you can look into the reason.  Eventually you will be able to read the fclose man page on your own and understand what went wrong.  Debugging is a skill you should strive to learn, even if you can only use printf or a sequence of LED blinks (depending on what your writing/building).

Comment: You still have a case where you will `fclose` a null pointer too. How is that `if` condition *ever* true ? `buffer[0] == 0xff` must be true, but `(buffer[0] & 0xf0) == 0xe0` must also be true. But if `buffer[0] == 0xff` is already true, `(buffer[0] & 0xf0)` is `0xf0`, not `0xe0`., so that block can never test true as a whole, which means `image` is never opened, which means `fclose(image)` invokes UB.

Comment: Thank you so much @WhozCraig. The code works great now.That was the problem it should have been (buffer[3] & 0xf0). I looked at the code so many times but couldn't see that. Very vigilante. That's a skill i'll be working on.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover filename\n");`  This code could be executed under any name, just by simply renaming the executable.  Suggest using the more typical: `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0] );`  Note: `argv[0]` always contains a pointer to a string that contains the name of the executable.

Comment: Do NOT delete information from your original question. That makes all comments and answers prior to the deletion not make sense. Instead, you may edit and **add below** your original question and correct any non-essential spelling or punctuation or indentation in the original, but don't delete content from it.

Comment: @user3629249 great tip I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sure. I didn't think of that. I'll remember that from next time. Thanks.

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "No file found\n");`  this not necessarily true.  Much better to use: `perror( "fopen failed" );` as that will output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: @user3629249 that's new . I'll try that out right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any segmentation error but I think you are mistaking the `fread` function.

> Return Value The total number of elements successfully read are
>   returned as a size_t object, which is an integral data type. If this
>   number differs from the nmemb parameter, then either an error had
>   occurred or the End Of File was reached.

So I don't know if you entered the loop or you were expecting something different.

You can do just do: `while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, file))`.

Comment: That **fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1** ensures that the loop exits when EOF is reached.

Comment: Can u try without ==1?as I told u in the answer it seems it returns the number of elements that has been read which might not be 1

Comment: Well that was not the problem for the seg fault (you can see the upper comments). It (the seg fault) was because the if condition was never true and I was just closing a NULL pointer image which had never opened. And for this matter instead of **fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1** I have also tried **fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512** and both work just fine.